# Enforce single required property on Typescript interface, allow others

Tags: typescript

I am creating a generic WebSocket component. I want to require the type `Message` to have a required property called `type`.

```js
export type Message = {
  type: string;
  [key: string]: any; // eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
};
```

The component is given a series of callback functions that are called when a `Message` of the appropriate `type` is called.

```js
export interface Listeners {
  [type: string]: (msg: Message) => void;
}
```

Code snippet of WebSocket implementation:

```js
...
ws.onmessage = (event: MessageEvent): void => {
  console.log("[websocket] got raw message", event.data);
  try {
    const msg = JSON.parse(event.data);

    if (listeners[msg.type]) {
      console.log("[websocket] got message", msg);
      listeners[msg.type](msg);
    }
  }
}
...
```

When using the WebSocket component, I'd like to define a custom type is an extension of the `Message` type, and includes the `type` property.

```js
interface GraphMessage extends Message {
  id: string;
  type: "initial" | "update";
  chartType: "line" | string;
  data: GraphPoint[];
}
```

I'm trying to use the component like so:

```js
const handleUpdate = (msg: GraphMessage) => {}
const handleInitial = (msg: GraphMessage) => {}

const ws = await websocket("ws://localhost:9999/", {
  initial: handleInitial,
  update: handleUpdate
});
```

However, I'm received a Typescript error:

```
TS2322: Type '(msg: GraphMessage) => void' is not assignable to type '(msg: Message) => void'. 
  Types of parameters 'msg' and 'msg' are incompatible. 
    Type 'Message' is not assignable to type 'GraphMessage'.
```

How can I make `Message` assignable to type `GraphMessage`?

**Edit:** I believe I've found a solution which is to make `Message` a generic type.

```js
type Message<T> = {
    type: string
    [key: string]: any
} & T

interface GraphMessage {
    graphName: string
}

type Callback = (msg: Message<GraphMessage>) => void

const myBaseMessage = {
    t...
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.7.5&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=25&pc=34#code/C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzCAeAKgPigXigG8AoKMqUSALinmACcBLAOxVPIG0BrCEGupqwC6NJMxDEAvlABkUTMWItgEegDMkAY2gBxekjAALOIlTQS5KCn1GAckgC2EfgxZtJiytADCSADZ+AEZaXPhQABQO8Cg0Jsho6HoGxgjxENgAlPi4AG4A9owAJoqaecx0UA4gAEJI8BBxZmEW5F40AEQAkradmJ0AggAy7VIlZRVVSUaNaM3sZG1QXT19Q+0ANPNWNob2Th3eeXl+UFOGIx7EpeXAUGCCwGczzlC+AcGaoQTh1snPsakzIkds9MtkiFtrvBjhAAHR+PIocLtHR5W5PQFoDbbP6YiAZUbEe7KDGmNCRECktIZIA)

Comment: With `listeners[msg.type](msg)`, `msg` can be *any* `Message`, not necessarily a `GraphMessage`.  If `listeners[msg.type]` expects `msg` to be a `GraphMessage` but it actually gets some other `Message`, it might do something bad like access the nonexistent `data` array.  There are any number of ways to address this, probably with either generics or with type guards inside your listener.  If you edit the code above into a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.7.5) I'd be happy to advise you.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz I believe I've found a solution. I've added a Playground link in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is right to point out that `Type '(msg: GraphMessage) => void' is not assignable to type '(msg: Message) => void'`.

If your handler depends on `GraphMessage` but you provide just a `Message`, this can result in runtime exceptions:

```
// Can, but doesn't have to include `id`
export type Message = {
    type: string;
    [key: string]: any;
};

interface GraphMessage extends Message {
  id: string;
  type: "initial" | "update";
}

const message: Message = {
    type: 'foo',
}

const handler = (msg: GraphMessage): void => {
    console.log(msg.type.toLocaleLowerCase());
}
```

If we do

```
handler(message); // Compile-time error
```

TypeScript will prevent an exception from being thrown.